# CPU затраты на расшифровку https трафика

Tags: linux, администрирование, ssl, https

Подскажите пожалуйста, необходимо на сервере проверить: сколько CPU-ресурса расходуется на  расшифровку https трафика.

Конкретнее - нужно убедиться, что ubuntu-сервер видеозаписи справится с входящим трафиком 200 Мбит/сек, трафик поступает через https-запрос на nginx, ssl-сертификаты рабочие. (Затем этот трафик идёт на PHP, откуда без изменений - записывается на SSD, но это уже не относится к теме вопроса)

Может быть есть простая linux утилита, чтобы осуществить такую проверку, может быть есть скриптик? А может быть всё можно рассчитать математически, подскажите кто сталкивался?

Comment: `iperf` ЕЯПП, ну и в этом ключе искать. `ntop` или как-то так ещё был.

Comment: Основной затратный процесс это установка соединения. Потом трафик шифруется относительно простым симметричным алгоритмом. Так что если у вас один долгий запрос, то разницу с http можно заметить только на чём-нибудь очень древнем.

Comment: @Alexey Ten спасибо, чувствуется уверенность в ваших словах, поэтому проверим уже в бою.